# How are critical values for correlation coefficients (product moment correlation coefficient) calculated?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, one-tailed-test

I have a fairly basic understanding of statistics. I've been learning about measuring correlation using product moment correlation coefficients (I think they're also called Pearson correlation coefficients). I was doing a simple one-tailed correlation hypothesis test and to check if the value of r is significant or not I had to find the critical value on a table given the number of trials (n) and the level of significance, 1% or 0.1 for example and rho = 0.
**The table:**
[image: table of values]

I was curious as to how these numbers were calculated, so I looked it up and the answers mentioned t-distribution and lots of other things I hadn't heard of and did not understand. Is there a formula that given n and the significance level gives the critical value of r shown on the table or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Can you give a reference/link for the table?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen [PDF link](https://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/A%20Level/Mathematics/2017/specification-and-sample-assesment/Pearson_Edexcel_A_Level_GCE_in_Mathematics_Formulae_Book.pdf), page 37